# how to compare to previous values in Seq[Double]

Tags: scala

I am new to functional programming, I have a Seq[Double] and I'd like to check for each value if it is higher (1), lower (-1) or equal (0) to previous value, like:

```
val g = Seq(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3)
```

and I'd like to have a result like:

```
val result = Seq(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1)
```

is there a more concise way than:

```
val g = Seq(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3)
g.sliding(2).toList.map(xs =>
 if (xs(0)==xs(1)){
    0
 } else if(xs(0)>xs(1)){
  -1
 } else {
    1
 }
)
```

Comment: If you want concision I'm not sure you can beat `(g.tail, g).zipped.map(_ compare _)`.

Comment: definitely a killer sentence, looks a bit hard to read for me tough... thanks very much

Comment: I agree that it's a bit harder to read. Zipping something against its tail to get consecutive element pairs is a pretty common functional idiom, though, so it's worth being aware of.

Comment: Yeah, functional idiom. I would choose this variant though compared to the accepted answer. The caveat being if you are working with a team, what can they easily support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `compare`:

```
g.sliding(2).map{ case Seq(x, y) => y compare x }.toList
```

`compare` is added by an enrichment trait called [`OrderedProxy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.OrderedProxy@compare(y:T):Int)

Comment: before I accept your answer, can you edit  => y compare x so to have the result I am looking for?

Comment: `compare`! I had a hunch something like that existed.

Comment: @user299791: my bad, I did not pay enough attention to the comparison order. Done.

Answer (score 1):

That's rather concise in my opinion but I'd make it a function and pass it into `map` to make it more readable. I used pattern matching and guards.

```
//High, low, equal
scala> def hlo(x: Double, y: Double): Int = y - x match {
     | case 0.0 => 0
     | case x if x < 0.0 => -1
     | case x if x > 0.0 =>  1
     | }
hlo: (x: Double, y: Double)Int

scala> g.sliding(2).map(xs => hlo(xs(0), xs(1))).toList
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 0, 0, -1)
```

Comment: an improvement to hlo:
`def hlo(x: Double, y: Double): Int = math.signum(y-x).toInt`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Travis Brown's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089476/how-to-compare-to-previous-values-in-seqdouble#comment57901999_35089476) from above so am proposing it as an answer.

Reversing the order of the values in the zip, just to match the order of `g`. This has the added benefit of using tuples instead of a sequence so no pattern matching is needed.

```
(g, g.tail).zipped.toList.map(t => t._2 compare t._1)


res0: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 0, 0, -1)
```